# subprocess.check_output(['git', 'shortlog'])

Tags: python, git, subprocess

`subprocess.check_output(['git', 'shortlog'])` returns empty bytes.
`subprocess.check_output(['git', 'log'])` works, somehow.
Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: thanks, `subprocess.check_output('git shortlog HEAD'.split())` works!